# Get Input from form for API url Request in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, weather-api

I'm new to Rails and I'm trying to make a simple weather API to get weather by zipcode
is there a way to get the zipcode from user input from a simple form, this will be just for learning so I'm not trying to make users devise, or users model

```
require 'net/http'
    require 'json'
    @url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=#{zipcode}&appid=APIKEY'
    @uri = URI(@url)
    @response = Net::HTTP.get(@uri) 
    @output = JSON.parse(@response)
```

Answer (score 0):

actually I figured it out, i needed to add

```
def zipcode
    @zip_query = params[:zipcode]
    
    if params[:zipcode] == ""
      @zip_query = "Hey you forgot to enter a zipcode!"
    elsif params[:zipcode]
      # Do Api stuff

      require 'net/http'
      require 'json'


      @url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip='+ @zip_query +'&appid=APIKEY'
      @uri = URI(@url)
      @response = Net::HTTP.get(@uri)
      @output = JSON.parse(@response)
      @name = @output['name']
    
    # Check for empty return result   
      if @output.empty?
        @final_output = "Error"
      elsif !@output
        @final_output = "Error"
      else
        @final_output = ((@output['main']['temp'] - 273.15) * 9/5 +32).round(2)
    end
    
    end
end
```

in the controller.rb file
and add

```
post "zipcode" => 'home#zipcode'
  get  "home/zipcode"
```

in the routes file
but I'm sure this is not the best practice

Comment: can we just redirect to a new page by passing the params and show the required data there?